# Piping output with SBT ProcessCommand

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to write an SBT task which stops a java application process called wiremock.

```
  lazy val `stop-wiremock` = taskKey[Unit]("Stop the wiremock server")
  lazy val stopWireMockTask = `stop-wiremock` in Performance := {
    "kill $(ps ux | grep [w]iremock | awk '{print $2}')".!
  }
```

Unfortunately this results in the output:

```
> stop-wiremock
kill: illegal process id: $(ps
kill: illegal process id: ux
kill: illegal process id: |
kill: illegal process id: grep
kill: illegal process id: [w]iremock
kill: illegal process id: |
kill: illegal process id: awk
kill: illegal process id: '{print
kill: illegal process id: $2}')
```

I don't know what the process builder is doing behind the scenes here but this doesn't work and [the documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html) tells me to use `operators` when building my command so I tried the following:

```
  lazy val `get-wiremock-pid` = taskKey[Unit]("Stop the wiremock server")
  lazy val getWiremockPidTask = `get-wiremock-pid` in Performance := {
    "ps ux" #| "grep [w]iremock" #| "awk '{print $2}'" !
  }
```

Now the error is:

```
> get-wiremock-pid
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
     >>> ' <<< 
    missing }
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

I suspect this is because the process builder has split the arguments to `awk` on the whitespace so it's only receiving `awk '{print` but I don't know how to rectify this.

Can anyone help me do this using the ProcessBuilder operators or even suggest a way I can just run the full command? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create Process from a sequence of string where first string is the command and remaining strings are parameters. For your case it will be

```
("ps ux" #| "grep [w]iremock" #|  Process(Seq("awk", "{print $2}"))) !
```